# Tailwind on Vuejs3 md: class overrides mobile first class

Tags: css, tailwind-css, vuejs3

I want to change the padding from px6 on mobile to px8 to anything bigger that 768px.
so I'm using "md:px-8". But seems this overrides the mobile behaviour when screen width is less than 768px? Basically px-6 never gets applied. Has anybody experienced/sorted this issue? Thanks.

on the Dev tools  I can see always (less or more 768px)

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.md\:px-8 {
    padding-left: 2rem;
    padding-right: 2rem;
}
and below:
.px-6 {
    padding-left: 1.5rem; <--- overriden (line in middle)
    padding-right: 1.5rem; <--- overriden (line in middle)
}
```

- I tried on Chrome, Safari, Firefox.
- I have the meta name="viewport"
  content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" on head
- All classes works except the responsiveness.

```
<template>
  <div class="flex flex-wrap flex-row">
    <div class="w-1/5 max-w-xs"></div>
    <div id="nav" class="bg-gray-900 w-1/5 max-w-xs h-screen px-6 py-8 md:px-8 fixed">
    <Navigation/
    </div>
    <div id="content" class="w-4/5 px-6 py-8 md:px-8">
      <router-view/>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: it works fine here https://play.tailwindcss.com/e1yf4Inpqw